# Is overriding __del__() the best choice here?

Tags: python, python-2.7, overriding, del

I am trying to figure out the best way to remove something, preferably without having to write in a lot of code.

In my project I am simulating chemical compounds - I have `Element` instances bonded to other `Element` instances via a `Bond` instance.  In chemistry bonds often break, and I'd like to have a clean way to do that.  My current method is something like as follows

```
# aBond is some Bond instance
#
# all Element instances have a 'bondList' of all bonds they are part of
# they also have a method 'removeBond(someBond)' that removes a given bond 
# from that bondList
element1.removeBond(aBond)
element2.removeBond(aBond)
del aBond
```

I want to do something like

```
aBond.breakBond()

class Bond():
    def breakBond(self):
        self.start.removeBond(self) # refers to the first part of the Bond 
        self.end.removeBond(self) # refers to the second part of the Bond 
        del self
```

Alternately, something like this would be fine

```
del aBond

class Bond():
    def __del__(self):
        self.start.removeBond(self) # refers to the first part of the Bond 
        self.end.removeBond(self) # refers to the second part of the Bond 
        del self
```

Is any one of these ways of doing it preferable to the others, or is there some other way of doing this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python uses garbage collection to manager memory, which means you do *not* have to delete anything. This class is fine:

```
class Bond():
    def breakBond(self):
        self.start.removeBond(self)
        self.end.removeBond(self)
```

note that `del` does **not** delete anything from memory! It simply removes a *reference* to an object, but objects can have more than one reference:

```
>>> some_list = [1,2,3]
>>> b = some_list
>>> del b   # destroys the list?
>>> b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>>> some_list   # list is still there!
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c = some_list
>>> del some_list
>>> c        # list is still there!
[1, 2, 3]
>>> del c
```

After the last `del c` the interpreter can deallocate the list. In CPython the deallocation will be done immediately (in this simple case), however in other implementation of the language the interpreter might not deallocate the list immediately.

Also note that [`__del__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)'s documentation cites this fact. Furthermore it is a **really** low-level method which you don't need 99.9% of the time, so it certainly *isn't* the right way to handle your situation.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I was expecting I would need to do.  Thank you (also) for clarifying how del works, I've never really understood that

Comment: One common use case for overriding `__del__` is for terminating threads or processes managed by the class. They won't be terminated by the garbage collector on their own.

Comment: @LeFrite Yes, but if you are **relying** on `__del__` to be called you are doing it wrong. It can be a holy mary, but if you have code handling resources you should properly and explcitly handle their release. `__del__` can *help* you in case someone calls `sys.exit` (but not `os._exit`!) and even then you have about a 50% chance that the `__del__` is called (see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983137/del-on-exit-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

The first way is pretty tedious and error-prone. The second is fine, but the `del self` in `Bond.breakBond` is completely and utterly pointless (more on this below). The third is hacky, unreliable, and in this specific case not working *at all* (due to the circular reference between Bond and Elements, `__del__` is never invoked unless you upgrade to Python 3.4, but even then it remains hacky and unreliable).

`del name` only removes the local `name`, it does not call `__del__` or otherwise affect the object. It has absolutely no effect on memory management, except possibly allowing earlier garbage collection if `name` was the last (reachable) reference.

You should do this:

```
aBond.breakBond()

class Bond():
    def breakBond(self):
        self.start.removeBond(self) # refers to the first part of the Bond 
        self.end.removeBond(self) # refers to the second part of the Bond
```

Comment: so for the last one if I used `aBond.__del__()` would it work?

Comment: @Dannnno It would run your code, i.e. call `self.end.removeBond(self)` and `self.start.removeBond(self)`. It would not free any objects or anything like that.