# __del__ on exit behavior

Tags: python, destructor, exit

I have some test.py file:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A init")

    def __del__(self):
        print("A del")

a = A()
```

When I run it 10 times (`python3 test.py`) it always produces next output:

```
A init
A del
```

But if I add `sys.exit` call to end of script:

```
import sys

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A init")

    def __del__(self):
        print("A del")

a = A()

sys.exit(-1)
```

in 5 of 10 cases (randomly) i have

```
A init
```

and in second half of cases:

```
A init
A del
```

I use Python3.4.3 [MSC v.1600 32 bit] on Windows 7 x64.
So why `__del__` method called not every time? Do I need to use some other exit method to pass return code of script and have all destructors guaranteed executed? And one more related question: is it possible to execute destructors on receive SIGTERM or SIGKILL from OS?

Comment: If you want to guarantee the clean-up method gets called, consider a context manager.

Comment: You should almost never use `__del__`. You can catch signals with the `signal` module, except for SIGKILL, which can't be caught.

Comment: Also, use `sys.exit(0);`, which means that the code worked properly.

Comment: 2L3viathan The thing why I want to use __del__, because I am writing wrapper to some .so library, which works with some OS audio resourses and it clearly says that I must call some deinit method on exit, or it may cause troubles when working with library on next launch which will be fixed only after reboot). So I want to call wrapper class in `__del__`. May be better decision to separate deinit in some other method and completely rely on users of wrapper?

Comment: 2AMACB I want to pass -1 as return code, only for example

Comment: @L3viathan except for SIGKILL and SIGSTOP*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

If you want to ensure that `a.__del__` is invoked, you'll have to explicitly delete the instance:

```
a = A()
del a   # Assuming this is the final reference to the object
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that calling `del a` doesn't necessarily mean that the object's `__del__` method gets called. That's only *sure* if you're using CPython and there are no other references to the object. In other situations, it may be subject to the whims of the garbage collector.