# multiprocessing.Queue.put_nowait blocks when used in destructor

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use a `multiprocessing.Queue` to communicate something when an object in another process which has this queue as an attribute is deleted. While doing so I noticed that `Queue.put()` with `block=False` (or equivalently `Queue.put_nowait()`) blocks anyway under certain circumstances and boiled it down to the following minimal reproducible example:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.q = mp.Queue()
    # uncommenting this makes it work fine:
    # self.q.put("test")

  def __del__(self):
    print("before putting CLOSE")
    self.q.put_nowait("CLOSE")
    print("after putting CLOSE")

a = A()

# uncommenting this also makes it work fine:
# del a
```

Running this code, the output gets as far as

```
before putting CLOSE
```

and then it freezes indefinitely.

I'm at a loss as to what's going on here and why this happens. `Queue.put_nowait()` seems to block if and only if it's called from an object's destructor (`__del__()`) *and* it hasn't had data put into it before *and* the destructor was called due to the object going out of scope rather than due to explicit `del`. The same exact thing happens if the queue is a global variable rather than an attribute of `A`, as long as `put_nowait()` is called within `A`'s destructor.

Interestingly, aborting the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't result in the usual exception output (`KeyboardInterrupt` etc.) but quits without any output.

Am I missing something obvious here? Why does this happen?

Comment: I think problem can be different then you think. When Python exits program then it may remove objects from memory in different way ithen using `del a` and this can make problem. I think I saw similar problem with deleting but with different functions. I'm not sure but problem can be that it may close all files before deleting object and if it has to use some file (ie. queue) then it can make problem.

Comment: I think it may explain problem a little - [__del__ on exit behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983137/del-on-exit-behavior)

Comment: @furas `__del__()` not necessarily being called on exit or object deletion is a good argument against doing the approach I was trying to do in the first place, so thanks for the advice. But I don't think it explains the blocking issue, because in all my tests, `__del__()` *was* called, as evidenced by the printed output.

Comment: it may call `__del__` after deleting queue so it may have problem to put anything in queue and it may block it.

Comment: @furas It must be something like that, yes. I'll use another approach like a context manager as suggested in the question you linked so I guess that's my issue taken care of, thanks!