# Why I can't delete (remove) the clearly 'existing instance' of the static list in Python?

Tags: python, static, instance

My purpose is as below:
If a new instance created, the instance must be added to the static list. and when a created instance is deleted, it must be deleted from the static list

And finalizer method, '**del**()' must be used.

The python code I had trouble with is as below:

```
class Staff:
    staffs = []  # static customer list

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("A staff is created!")

    def __del__(self):
        Staff.staffs.remove(self)
        print("A staff is deleted!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a staff
    Staff.staffs.append(Staff("Harry"))

    # delete a staff
    Staff.staffs[0].__del__()
```

And the error is as below:

Exception ignored in: <function Staff.**del** at 0x0000028A3675EF70>

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "(Path)\temp.py", line 11, in **del**
Staff.staffs.remove(self)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

And I can check that the created instance exists in the static list like below code

```
def check(self):
    print("Length of Static List:", len(Staff.staffs))
    print("self", self)
    for a_staff in Staff.staffs:
        if a_staff == self:
            print("a_staff", a_staff)
    print()
```

Result:

Length of Static List: 1

self <**main**.Staff object at 0x000001FF7506CFD0>

a_staff <**main**.Staff object at 0x000001FF7506CFD0>

The memory addresses of the instances are totally the same but I don't know why the interpreter says that there is no instance in the static list.

When I ran similar code in Java there was no problem.

Why does the error occur?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Save the instance of the Staff object in a list then when the instance is deleted remove it from the list?

Comment: @DanielButler Thank you for answering! Yes, right. If a new instance created, the instance must be added to the static list. and when a created instance is deleted, it must be deleted from the static list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

```
class Staff:
    staffs = []  # static customer list

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("A staff is created!")

    def delete(self):
        Staff.staffs.remove(self)
        print("A staff is deleted!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a staff
    Staff.staffs.append(Staff("Harry"))

    # delete a staff
    Staff.staffs[0].delete()
```

works fine. All I have done is renamed `__del__` to delete. You can try to interpret the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) on it which notes that

> Due to the precarious circumstances under which **del**() methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to sys.stderr instead.

The above quote explains your error. However, as [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21766679/11659881) outline, `__del__` is a

> really low-level method which you don't need 99.9% of the time

so it should be sufficient to just use the code above, which marks your instance for garbage collection.

If you must add additional content to the `__del__` command, try this:

```
class Staff:
    staffs = []  # static customer list

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("A staff is created!")

    def __del__(self):
        print("A staff is deleted!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a staff
    Staff.staffs.append(Staff("Harry"))

    print(f"The length of Staff before delete is: {len(Staff.staffs)}")
    # delete a staff
    del Staff.staffs[0]
    print(f"The length of Staff after delete is: {len(Staff.staffs)}")
```

This outputs:

> A staff is created!
> The length of Staff before delete is: 1
> A staff is deleted!
> The length of Staff after delete is: 0

So the item is deleted, and your text is printed, with no exception!

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understood that your method works well. but the finalizer method (__del__()) must be used...

Comment: @JEONOUS See my edit, as it may be more of use to you

Comment: Thank you for answering again. but I have a question. In python, I can check the instance that exists in the static list, but why do I can't remove it with remove()?

Comment: Your answer is perfect and I understood it. In fact, though the reason is not written here, I should delete the instance of the static list inside of __del__().

Comment: @JEONOUS As one final note, when you override `__del__()` you are defining `del`. You should be using `del`. Just as you write `len(Staff.staffs)` instead of `Staff.staffs.__len__()`