# How to free all GPU memory from pytorch.load?

Tags: memory-management, pytorch, google-colaboratory

This code fills some GPU memory and doesn't let it go:

```
def checkpoint_mem(model_name):
    checkpoint = torch.load(model_name)
    del checkpoint
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Printing memory with the following code:

```
print(torch.cuda.memory_reserved(0))
print(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0))
```

shows BEFORE running `checkpoint_mem`:

```
0
0
```

and AFTER:

```
121634816
97332224
```

This is with `torch.__version__` `1.11.0+cu113` on Google colab.

Does `torch.load` leak memory?  How can I get the GPU memory completely cleared?

Answer (score 3):

It probably doesn't. Also, it depends on what you call memory leak. In this case, after the program ends all memory should be freed, python has a garbage collector, so it might not happen immediately (your `del` or after leaving the scope) like it does in C++ or similar languages with RAII.

### `del`

1. `del` is called by Python and only removes the reference (same as when the object goes out of scope in your function).
2. `torch.nn.Module` **does not implement `del`**, hence its reference is simply removed.
3. All of the elements within `torch.nn.Module` have their references removed recursively (so for each CUDA `torch.Tensor` instance their `__del__` is called).
4. `del` on each tensor is a call to release memory

More about [`__del__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21766679)

### Caching allocator

Another thing - caching allocator occupies part of the memory so it doesn't have to rival other apps in need of CUDA when you are going to use it.

Also, I assume PyTorch is loaded lazily, hence you get `0` MB used at the very beginning, but AFAIK PyTorch itself, during startup, reserves some part of CUDA memory.

The short story is given [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/faq.html#my-gpu-memory-isn-t-freed-properly), longer one [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#memory-management) in case you didn’t see it already.

### Possible experiments

- You may try to run `time.sleep(5)` after your function and measure afterwards.
- You can get snapshot of the allocator state via [`torch.cuda.memory_snapshot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.memory_snapshot.html#torch.cuda.memory_snapshot) to get more info about allocator’s reserved memory and inner workings.
- You might set the environment variable `PYTORCH_NO_CUDA_MEMORY_CACHING=1` and see whether and if anything changes.

### Disclaimer

Not a CUDA expert by any means, so someone with more insight could probably expand (and/or correct) my current understanding as I am sure way more things happen under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, see here for the same question and the response from PyTorch developer:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/37664